# Crashes and freezes after fixing "BOOTMGR is missing" error

Tags: freeze, crash, hardware-failure, bootmgr

I came back from a 3-day weekend to a computer that was off. I leave my PC on 24/7, so this was odd.

Turn it on to get the dreaded "BOOTMGR is missing" screen.

Two attempts at Windows Recovery and it booted into Windows fine.

After an hour or so, I get a frozen Chrome and my start bar disappears. Ctrl+Alt+Del brings up an error box telling me that Ctrl+Alt+Del failed to work properly. Clicking on any open application triggers an error (I can't recall the error now, but it essentially just said that the application couldn't be found running or something along those lines).

I restart, and again, the same thing happens after a while of use.

I turn it on, install the 47 updates I have or so, and then restart it. After a while of use (under an hour), it just freezes completely.

My thoughts are: SSDs, RAM or PS.

My system specs below:

- (RAID0) 2 x Crucial M4 CT128M4SSD2 2.5" 128GB SATA III MLC Internal Solid State Drive (SSD)
- CORSAIR Vengeance 16GB (4 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model CML16GX3M4A1600C9
- CORSAIR HX Series HX750 750W ATX12V 2.3 / EPS12V 2.91 SLI Ready CrossFire Ready 80 PLUS GOLD Certified Modular Active
- 1 x ASUS Maximus IV Gene-Z/GEN3 LGA 1155 Intel Z68 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 Micro ATX Intel Motherboard
- 1 x Hitachi GST Deskstar 7K1000.C 0F10383 1TB 7200 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s 3.5" Internal Hard Drive -Bare Drive
- 1 x Intel Core i7-2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4GHz (3.8GHz Turbo Boost) LGA 1155 95W Quad-Core Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics
- 1 x SAPPHIRE 21197-00-40G Radeon HD 7970 3GB 384-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready CrossFireX Support Video Card
- 1 x Noctua NH-D14 120mm & 140mm SSO CPU Cooler

This is all crammed in a pretty small case (NZXT Vulcan) and has been running perfectly problem-free since January.

The only thing out of the ordinary is that there is a fan in the case that is now making noise whereas the case has previously been completely silent. I have no reason to believe this is anything more then correlation, but felt it is worth mentioning.

I believe it MAY be the SSDs simply because of the BOOTMGR error, but not sure how to test that theory.

My belief that it may be the RAM is simply from experience with frozen machines. I haven't had the time to memtest it, but will.

The PS being the culprit is something I've picked up by reading similar threads on various forums, and it seems plausible. I am unsure how to test this though.

ANY insight whatsover would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explicitly mention if the SSDs or the HDD was your boot device, but I am assuming SSD, due to your comments.

The freezing as you describe it, would seem to be caused by bad CPU voltage (power supply), bad RAM (memory errors), or a bad drive/controller.

Here are possible points of failure that come to mind, in order of easiest/cheapest to test.

2. RAM -- Run memtest
3. Power supply -- Swap it out with another (these are fairly inexpensive)
4. SSD failure -- Clone the RAID onto a different drive (may be cheaper than #2 if you have a spare drive)
5. RAID controller failure -- Install and test with a new RAID PCI controller

Comment: So here is the outcome: 

RAM passed memtest several times with no errors. The system didn't freeze during any of these tests, nor has it frozen since, so no reason to believe it is the PS at this point either. I put SATA mode to AHCI mode and am now running a brand-new single SSD instead of RAID. I have had no hiccups since re-installing windows on the new drive and neither of the old RAIDed SSDs failed HD Tune Pro Error Scans. I am at a complete loss on what the issue could have been.

Comment: Perhaps I spoke to soon... At some point during me using my computer this evening, BOTH SSD drives that use to make up the RAID 0 array no longer show up in Windows (neither as part of explorer, or Disk Management). I believe it is time to RMA the motherboard.